# How do I clear imageView of UIButton in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview

I have UIButton called menuButton which has a customClass where it sets multiple images and I have a dropDown menu when we click on it. So based on menu selected I want to menuButton to change the image.

This is my code:

```
public enum MenuItems: String {
  case menu1 = "menu1"
  case menu2 = "menu2"
  case menu3 = "menu3"
}

func layoutView() {
     menuButton.setImages(normalImage: "triangleImage",
                                  image: "menu1",
                                  selectedImage: "closeImage")
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuItemTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.addSubview(menuButton)
}

func menuItemTapped(sender: UIView) {
    guard let title = sender.accessibilityIdentifier else { return }
    let style = MenuItems(rawValue: title)
    
    switch style {
    case .menu1:
      menuButton.setImages(normalImage: "triangleImage",
                                  image: "menu1",
                                  selectedImage: "closeImage")
    case .menu2:
       menuButton.setImages(normalImage: "triangleImage",
                                  image: "menu2",
                                  selectedImage: "closeImage")
    case .menu3:
       menuButton.setImages(normalImage: "triangleImage",
                                  image: "menu3",
                                  selectedImage: "closeImage")
    default:
      break
    }
}

class MultipleImageButton: UIButton {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func setImages(normalImage: UIImage, image: UIImage, selectedImage: UIImage) {
    setImage(normalImage, for: .normal)
    setImage(selectedImage, for: .selected)
    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0_5x, left: 1x, bottom: 0_5x, right: (bounds.maxX - 55))
    contentHorizontalAlignment = .right


for subview in self.subviews where subview.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()//removes images if any
  }
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + 4x,
                                                  y: (titleLabel?.bounds.midY ?? 0) + 1x,
                                                      width: 5x,
                                                  height: frame.height - 2_5x))
    
        imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        addSubview(imageView)
      }
    }
```

Using the above code I'm able to change the button image(i.e. imageView) but its not adding the selectedImage and normalImage only the image is getting changed. How do I get the selectedImage and normalImage to display as well?
[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnZV4.png)

[This is the problem now,  which doesn't display triangle image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XxjB.png)

Comment: `.normal` and `.selected` are probably set, but overridden later in your `for subview in self.subviews` loop. Have you tried to move the loop before standard `setImage` calls?

Comment: @lazarevzubov yes it's the same behavior.It doesn't display selectedImage and normalImage.

Comment: You said "I have UIButton called menuButton which has a customClass..." What does "which has a customClass" mean? Does it mean you have created a custom subclass of UIButton that you have called MultipleImageButton, maybe? As it is, I don't understand what that sentence means.

Comment: @DuncanC yes the customClass is MultipleImageButton()

Answer (score 1):

How do I clear imageView of UIButton in swift?

**Answer:** `button.(UIImage(), for: .normal)`

> Its Simply remove your image from button

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps with a simple `UIButton`; it is not needed to use a custom `Button` class.

When clicking `menuButton`, set the button image to `closeImage` and show the dropdown:

```
menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "closeImage"), for: .normal)
// show Dropdown
```

When you select the menu item, change the `menuButton` image and hide the dropdown:

```
menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "selectedItem"), for: .normal)
//hide dropdown
```

Comment: The problem is not just changing these images, I want to change "menu1", "menu2", "menu3" images also which is a UIImageView.

Comment: where did you place UIImageView?

Comment: Inside setImages()

Comment: I mean to say in design

Comment: let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + 4x,
                                                  y: (titleLabel?.bounds.midY ?? 0) + 1x,
                                                      width: 5x,
                                                  height: frame.height - 2_5x))
    
        imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        addSubview(imageView)

Comment: if you share a image what you want i will help you better

Comment: if Button already have a image property why you added one more image in it?

Comment: I think you want two images in same button right?

Comment: Yes please check my edited question I have added Image.

Comment: i suggest you to take to 2 UIImageView in horizontal stackView and place a button on it, on click button you can change the images and update your send image as well

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. It worked when I have 2 imageViews.